# How to force a full recalculation of an Excel sheet using vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am a beginner at visual basic and this is my first stack overflow question, so I'm sorry if this is a mess. I am trying to take values entered from a windows form and enter them into an excel sheet. I used search and replace to achieve this. I have been able to successfully get that far. My only problem now, is that excel will not calculate the values entered into the sheet. Excel will only calculate those functions if I manually go in and reset each cell (with F2). I have my calculation on automatic as well.

```
Dim excelReplacements As New List(Of Array)
   ' Create list to hold hold excel replacements
    excelReplacements.Add({"utilCost", 
ExclusiveUtilityRate.Value + SharedUtilityRate.Value})
    excelReplacements.Add({"intCost", Internet.Value})
    excelReplacements.Add({"pCost", PhoneCost})
    excelReplacements.Add({"pUnits", PhoneQty.Value})


'Select sheet 2
workbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate()

Try
        'loop though excelReplacements and replace every key with it's value
         For Each rep In excelReplacements
             Dim ranges As CellRange() = 
                 sheet.FindAllString(Convert.ToString(rep.GetValue(0)), False, False)
             For Each range As CellRange In ranges
             If rep.GetValue(0) Is "pCost" Then
                 sheet.Replace("pCost", Convert.ToDouble(PhoneCost.Value))
             ElseIf rep.GetValue(0) Is "pUnits" Then
                 sheet.Replace("pUnits", Convert.ToDouble(PhoneQty.Value))
             Else
                 Dim value As Long = Convert.ToDouble(rep.GetValue(1))
                                    sheet.Replace(range.Value, value)
             End If

         Next
     Next
Catch e1 As System.Exception
     'if couldn't find the word,give a message
     Console.WriteLine("The text doesn't exist the word you want to replace")

End Try
Output.AppendText("Changes Made...")
    ' save workbook
     workbook.SaveToFile(xlssave, FileFormat.Version2013)
     workbook.Worksheets.Remove("Evaluation Warning")

     xlsApp.Quit()
     Output.AppendText("Worksheet Saved" & Environment.NewLine)
```

I have done a lot of research, but I have only found information on vba, which I am not using. I 
I have the following imports:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Spire.Xls
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
```

If you need more of my code I will gladly show you. If there is any way to force a full calculation using vb.net (praying there is) or if you see an error in my code that is causing excel to not calculate the values, please let me know.

Comment: does `workbook.Calculate` work? (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-method-excel)

Comment: u want to calculate what ? Do u want to calculate how many data is there ?

Comment: I have functions that depend on those values. For example, I have a function that calculates the amount that a client would pay for phone service by multiplying the number of phones by the base rate per phone. # of phones is a value that is entered through the windows form. I hope that made sense

Comment: @ilja workbook.calculate produces an error. 'Calculate' is not a member of 'workbook.'

Comment: sorry, forgotten the `()`, so could you try `workbook.Calculate()` at the end or on the worksheet `workbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Calculate()`?

Comment: @zackraiyan Congratulations! over 1,000! and in only 4 months. Way to go!

Comment: yes.....I am active for almost 19+ hours each day :)

Comment: @Mary,thank you that you wished me ... Am i the only one to get 1K+ rep so fast ?? I dnt think so ?

Comment: If making Excel files from .NET I'd encourage you to look at [ClosedXml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML). It is much nicer to work with than Interop and you don't need Excel installed on the machine which is making the Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Try `xlsApp.CalculateFull`. The calculation methods work at the application level, not the workbook level.

The `.Calculate` method also works at the Worksheet and Range level. This may also help as calculating a smaller range will be quicker than doing the full calculation across all open workbooks in the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the VB code, the Excel spreadsheet using it does not realize it's changed and so does not recalculate. However, anything that convinces Excel to recalculate a cell containing a call to the now modified VB function will force it to execute for that cell. Also editing the cell, even just hitting F2 and Enter, will work. However, if you have a lot of cells using the function, it would be a pain. A **Solution** I've found: do a Find and Replace of the (full) function name and click Replace All... bingo!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the .Calculate Method in order to force calculate.